# create string with variable number of spaces in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm having trouble creating a string in clojure, I need to insert a series of blank spaces depending on the length on one of the string variables - book.

```
(defn blanks [book]
    (let [ x(count book)]
    (cond 
            (= "4" x) "    "
            (= "5" x) "     "
            (= "6" x ) "      "
)))

(defn Key1 [x date book bookid]
    (cond 
            (= "AB.LN.TUV" x) (str date".                  AB.LN.  TUV. JKL.      FOO.           FOO.   GRAVITY.       "book".book."(str (blanks book)) bookid)
            (= "DEF.NY.ZXY" x) (str date". DEF.NY. ZXY. JKL.     .          .QPR.             "book".  POS.        "book"."bookid)
            (= "DEF.LN.TUV" x ) (str date".                DEF.LN.  TUV. JKL.      FOO.           FOO.   GRAVITY.       "book".book."blanks bookid)
))



(defn ShowSelectedParams [& props] 
    (let [
              entity "AB.LN.TUV"


              book "ABCD"
              date "21030823"
              bookid "1234abcd"
              ]

              (Key1 entity date book bookid)
))
```

However this returns the following, without the spaces:

"21030823.                  AB.LN.  TUV. JKL.      FOO.           FOO.   GRAVITY.       ABCD.**book.1234abcd**"

What I want to get is:

"21030823.                  AB.LN.  TUV. JKL.      FOO.           FOO.   GRAVITY.       ABCD.**strong text**book.    1234abcd"

Any help with this much appreciated

Comment: Nevermind, just realised I had the cond checking for string not numbers! DOH!!If anyone knows a more clojuresqu way of doing this though I would be very interested..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is an attempt to make it a bit more idiomatic

I applied a more standard clojure style to the formatting, generated the number of blanks based on the count rather than hard coding the strings, and replaced the repeated equality checks with a case statement.

```
(defn blanks
  [book]
  (apply str (repeat (count book) \space)))


(defn Key1
  [x date book bookid]
  (case x
    "AB.LN.TUV" (str date
                     ".AB.LN.TUV.JKL.FOO.FOO.GRAVITY."
                     book ".book."
                     (blanks book)
                     bookid)
    "DEF.NY.ZXY" (str date
                      ".DEF.NY.ZXY.JKL...QPR."
                      book
                      ".POS."
                      book
                      "."
                      bookid)
    "DEF.LN.TUV" (str date
                      ".DEF.LN.TUV.JKL.FOO.FOO.GRAVITY."
                      book
                      ".book."
                      blanks
                      bookid)))

(defn ShowSelectedParams
  [& props] 
  (let [entity "AB.LN.TUV"
        book "ABCD"
        date "21030823"
        bookid "1234abcd"]
    (Key1 entity date book bookid)))
```

Comment: I think this still isn't right, for example putting the function blanks in the result string of the third case is probably an error.